# cakephp 2.0 hasmany relation retrieve data

Tags: count, cakephp-2.0, has-many

I have two model name image and comment. here the relation is like image has many comments . Now in my listing page I want to display all imae detail and only the no of comment on that image . can you tell me how should I get that ?
after I write the query my return data is

```
Array
(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [Image] => Array
                (
                    [image_id] => 57
                    [user_id] => 1
                    [category_id] => 22
                    [image_title] => scroul
                    [description] => beutifull natural image for the animal
                    [keyword] => scrual
                    [image_price] => 
                    [image_name] => 7bf4a72509da5906903c84e88228b9dd.jpg
                    [image_path] => img/uploads/images/original/
                    [image_available_size] => 
                    [like] => 12
                    [size] => 3244
                    [resolution] => 2162 x 1644
                    [i_date] => 1348573022
                    [i_by] => 1
                    [u_date] => 1348573022
                    [u_by] => 1
                    [is_active] => Y
                    [is_deleted] => N
                )

            [Comment] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [comment_id] => 5
                            [image_id] => 57
                            [user_id] => 2
                            [comment] => socute
                            [comment_date] => 1348739230
                            [is_active] => N
                            [is_deleted] => N
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Image] => Array
                (
                    [image_id] => 56
                    [user_id] => 1
                    [category_id] => 22
                    [image_title] => cute dog
                    [description] => cute dog looking 
                    [keyword] => 
                    [image_price] => 
                    [image_name] => d4af899b0d52cccbec94952a3abd0077.jpg
                    [image_path] => img/uploads/images/original/
                    [image_available_size] => 
                    [like] => 8
                    [size] => 620
                    [resolution] => 2592 x 1944
                    [i_date] => 1348572897
                    [i_by] => 1
                    [u_date] => 1348572897
                    [u_by] => 1
                    [is_active] => Y
                    [is_deleted] => N
                )

            [Comment] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [comment_id] => 3
                            [image_id] => 56
                            [user_id] => 2
                            [comment] => ohhhhhhh
                            [comment_date] => 1348737968
                            [is_active] => N
                            [is_deleted] => N
                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Image] => Array
                (
                    [image_id] => 55
                    [user_id] => 1
                    [category_id] => 22
                    [image_title] => ships
                    [description] => ships with beutiful green background
                    [keyword] => ship,green,animal,nature,background,eating,white ship
                    [image_price] => 
                    [image_name] => c0dfc2432ae047e9160f3ef99880fe87.jpg
                    [image_path] => img/uploads/images/original/
                    [image_available_size] => 
                    [like] => 1
                    [size] => 1831
                    [resolution] => 2520 x 1944
                    [i_date] => 1348572846
                    [i_by] => 1
                    [u_date] => 1348661976
                    [u_by] => 1
                    [is_active] => Y
                    [is_deleted] => N
                )

            [Comment] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [comment_id] => 2
                            [image_id] => 55
                            [user_id] => 2
                            [comment] =>  i like it
                            [comment_date] => 1348737942
                            [is_active] => Y
                            [is_deleted] => N
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [comment_id] => 4
                            [image_id] => 55
                            [user_id] => 2
                            [comment] =>  good scene
                            [comment_date] => 1348738004
                            [is_active] => N
                            [is_deleted] => N
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

in the above array there is a all comment of that image. I don't want here comment list I just want no  of comments .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you post the find statement you're using. You can set recursive to a certain level, from the documentation:

> - -1 Cake fetches Group data only, no joins.
> - 0 Cake fetches Group data and its domain
> - 1 Cake fetches a Group, its domain and its associated Users
> - 2 Cake fetches a Group, its domain, its associated Users, and the Users’ associated Articles

So you can call the following if you only want the data from the current model only:

```
$this->Model->find('all', array('recursive' => -1));
```

There is also the [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) behavior, which allows you to specify which Model data you want to retrieve when calling `find`.

Say you have a Post model which `hasMany` Image. The call, with the Containable behaviour in the Post Model properly included, would be:

```
$this->Post->find('all', array(
 'conditions' => array('Post.id' => 1),
 'contain' => array('Image')
));
```

**EDIT:**
Because of the spelling and formatting I misread your initial question. I thought you wanted *"no comments"* to appear in the data array, instead you want only the *"number of comments"* to appear.

If you want the comment count, use [counterCache](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#countercache-cache-your-count) as Kishor Kundan proposes.

Answer (score 1):

Cake offers another amazing magic, "counterCache".

You can define the counterCache in your Comments model

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'className' => 'Image',
    'foreignKey' => <your_foreign_key>,
    ...
    ...
    'counterCache' => true

);
```

Then you add a field, 'comment_count' in your images table (or the table which is being used by the model Image) and the cake will do the rest for you.

This does add an overhead every time a comment is added/deleted but it is far better alternative than to issue an 'count' every time you fetch image data.

For more info you can check [the cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#belongsto). Look out for "counterCache" there.

**UPDATE:**

To limit the scope for counter cache, use additional attribute 'counterScope' as

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'className' => 'Image',
    'foreignKey' => <your_foreign_key>,
    ...
    ...
    'counterCache' => true,
    'counterScope' => array('Image.active' => 1)

);
```

Comment: its very helpful to me but still i have one issue. in my project if user add comment, by default its deactive then also in image master value of comment_count will increase by 1, i dont want that. when admin make that comment active then i want to increase the comment_count.  can you help me  ?